# How to workaround "redefinition of default parameter" in class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

Consider the following example:

```
class Rectangle{
    Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height);
    Rectangle(int topLeft_x, int topLeft_y, int bottomRight_x, int bottomRight_y);    
};
```

A Rectangle object may be built giving (x,y) coordinates plus width and height or giving top left points pair and bottom right points pair.

While this is correct from an object oriented point of view, this is not from a compiler point of view, returning the error "member function already defined or declared"

While I normally fix this condition easily in case of member function, simply changing the name according to what it does, this is not possible for constructors.

What is the simpler and correct way to workaround this issue keeping both the way to construct the object?

Comment: There are no default parameters here, so the compiler must be complaining about some other code. The problem here is that the two declarations are the same. Changing the names of the arguments doesn't affect that.

Comment: @PeteBecker: EDIT: error message correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution (other than the pair suggested by @VladfromMoscow) is a static method to perform construction.  This lets you give them distinct names, since their argument lists are so similar.  Thisi is called the [Named Constructor Idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom)

```
class Rectangle
{
 public:
   static Rectangle createRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) 
   {
      return Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
   }
   static Rectangle createRectangleCorners(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) 
   {
      return Rectangle(x1,y1,x2-x1, y2-y1); 
   }
 private:
   // Doesn't have to be private, but this forces users to use the above 
   // constructors
   Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote already yourself

> top left **points** pair and bottom right **points** pair

So what you need is to define class `Point` and use this type in the constructor declaration.

Otherwise the constructors are declared like

```
class Rectangle{
    Rectangle(int, int, int, int);
    Rectangle(int, int, int, int);    
};
```

As you see these declarations do not make sense even if you will write multiline comments.:)

Another approach is to declare the first constructor like

```
class Rectangle{
    Rectangle(int x, int y, unsigned int width, unsigned int height);
    Rectangle(int topLeft_x, int topLeft_y, int bottomRight_x, int bottomRight_y);    
};
```

However this approach is unsafe because each integer literal specified as the third or fourth argument must be casted.

Instead of the class `Point` you could use standard class `std::pair`. For example

```
#include <utility>

//...

class Rectangle{
    Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height);
    Rectangle( const std::pair<int, int> &topLeft, const std::pair<int, int> &bottomRight);    
};
```

Comment: Nice solution. Any other way without creating a new class just with the scope to manage this?

Comment: I would use "unsigned int" instead of "size_t" as width and height as they describe better what the range of the variable is and the have the same size as int.

Comment: @ABCplus You can use standard class std::pair

Comment: I partially agree with the updated solution: in case you add a constructor that takes topRight points pair and bottomLeft pair you end up again in a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Another way on how to solve this problem is by using [Tag dispatching](http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/cpp/techniques.php#tag_dispatching):

Instead of using methods with different names, give them a new parameter, e.g.,

```html
struct useCorners {};
struct useDimension {};

class Rectangle
{
    Rectangle(useCorners, int topLeft, int topRight, int bottomLeft, int bottomRight) 
    { ...
    }
    Rectangle(useDimension, int topLeft, int topRight, int width, int height) 
    { ... 
    }
};
```